# regression coefficients in KXEN

Tags: sql, statistics, sas, regression

we are considering to start using kxen to build logistic regression models on client data. We have used SAS and R studio till now and I am having hard times to clearly understand the logic of K2R package used in Kxen.

1) how can one obtain regression coefficients from `Kxen - (beta, intercept)` in case I want to build scoring function in sql ?

got following sql code out (part of code enclosed):

```
SELECT $key, $target_variable, CAST( (CASE 
    WHEN $target_variable <= -1.32354053933e0 THEN 0.0e0
    WHEN $target_variable <= -3.245405264555e-1 THEN 0.0e0
    WHEN $target_variable <= -3.235405393301e-1 THEN  ( 2.283134417281e-3*$target_variable+7.409696685844e-4 ) 
    WHEN $target_variable <= -2.673812457267e-1 THEN  ( 4.065409082516e-5*$target_variable+1.543635190092e-5 ) 
    WHEN $target_variable <= -"2.673250302176e-1 THEN  ( 4.057282329758e1*"$target_variable"+1.084841700789e1 ) 
    ..... [more code here]
    ELSE 0.0e0
    END) AS FLOAT )
AS PROBA0 
into [table_name]
FROM 
(
    SELECT $key, ( 2.191922889118e-2 + CAST( (CASE 
        WHEN ( "predictor1" IS NULL OR "predictor1" = ''  ) THEN -6.39011247354e-3
        WHEN "predictor1" <= -2.432307283e0 THEN -1.541583426389e-1
        WHEN "predictor1" <= 9.41313103e-1 THEN  ( 9.932069236689e-2*"predictor1"+8.742010175092e-2 ) 
        WHEN "predictor1" <= 1.696595422e0 THEN  ( 4.169961790129e-2*"predictor1""+2.454336172985e-1 ) 
        WHEN "predictor1" >= 1.696595402e0 THEN 3.16180997712e-1
        ELSE -6.39011247354e-3
    END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
    WHEN ( "predictor2" IS NULL OR "predictor2" = ''  ) THEN 3.937894402762e-3
    WHEN "predictor2" <= -9.99550198e-1 THEN -2.797353866946e-2
    WHEN "predictor2" <= -1.27770581e-1 THEN  ( 2.918798485695e-2*"predictor2""+1.201317665409e-3 ) 
    WHEN "predictor2" <= 3.78487285e-1 THEN  ( 2.547969219572e-2*"predictor2"+6.997428207111e-3 ) 
    ...... [more code here]

) AS $target_varialbe FROM [table_name]
) TMPTABLE0
```

predictors are all inputed after WOE transformation and defined as continuous variables.

2) when ordering customers by score assigned the order is different then when ordering by probability - ergo conversion from score to probability is not monotonous function? the aim for me is to have normalized score/probability assigned to customer.

can anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 1):

as I was eventually able to find out the answer, here it comes:
KXEN K2R engine used for robust regression is not exactly comparable to SAS or R as they use different logic. KXEN regression engine is built based on Structural Risk Minimization using Vapniks theorem, transforming predictors in score calculation (score is not normalized) and then using set of logistic equations on different score bins to get probability for target variable, normalized from 0 to 1. One is therefore unable to extract regression coefficients from KXEN. Also score to probability is not strictly monotonous function